# update one column based on other column value

Tags: db2

I have a table where if same name comes it should have same id if not then I need to update the Id column with lowest id number if the name is same.

My data looks like this

Name | Id
AAA  | 1
AAA  | 2
BBB  | 4
BBB  | 4
BBB  | 5

the output should be

Name | Id
AAA  | 1
AAA  | 1
BBB  | 4
BBB  | 4
BBB  | 4

Comment: Please, format the question and make sure the presentation is correct before posting a question. Put 4 espaces before each escaped line (no format)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OLAP functions for that.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html